# How do we know when to use articles or not?

Tags: articles

> 1. I finished writing a report last night.
> 2. His hobby is writing poems.

Why in number 2 is an article not used before the word "poems"? Is it because "poems" is plural? If so, why then don't we use "the" before it since "the" is the plural definite article?

> 2. His hobby is writing the poems.

When do and when don't we use articles before nouns?
Or do we always have to use articles before nouns?

Answer (score 2):

In the sentence

> His hobby is writing the poems

the article *the* changes the meaning and adds ambiguity.

> Poems

and

> The poems

imply two different things.  In the second case, *the* refers to specific poems.  What those poems are is anybody's guess.  To avoid this kind of ambiguity, the sentence should be generalized:

> His hobby is writing poems

Where the hobby is the general act of writing poems.

Answer (score 1):

We don't use an article when talking about things in general.  This is called the [Zero Article](http://www.icaltefl.com/zero-article-in-english-grammar).

In your example he is writing poems in general, so no article is needed.

> His hobby is writing poems.

If he's writing some specific poems then an article is needed.

> His hobby is writing the poems for our annual Christmas show.

Comment: Thanks ssav. Is there any condition to use zero article beside things in general?

Comment: The linked article lists the other conditions when zero articles are used and has lots of examples.  Proper nouns like names are probably the most common.